# JupyterLab Job Scheduler

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, job-scheduling

I'm using the job scheduler with JupyterLab. I've noticed that when I run my code manually it will output and save the desired .csv file. However, when I run this piece of code using the JupyterLab Job Scheduler it will execute without error, but it won't save and/or update the excel files the same way it did for the manual iteration.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried a few different settings but there is not much to work with. I am expecting an output file if there is not one matching the given name. Otherwise, I am expecting the code to write over the existing output file in the event the name is already in use. As I mentioned the code works fine manually, this is just an issue with the JupyterLab job scheduler.